# Problems connecting a Rest API to my Django project

Tags: python, django

I'm having a lot of problems connecting a REST API, in this case the Mayan Edms one, with my Django application.

I want to make all the documents that arrive or simply that are in my mayan, I can see it in my Django interface. Can anyone give me a hand?

Below, I attach the code of the function that I have tried to do and that does not work.

```
@login_required
def f_facturaspendientes(request):
    # URL de la API a la que deseas conectarte
    url = 'http://localhost/api/v4/documents/'

    try:
        # Realiza una solicitud GET a la API
        response = requests.get(url)

        # Comprueba si la solicitud fue exitosa (código de estado 200)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            # Convierte la respuesta JSON en un diccionario de Python
            datos = response.json()
            return datos

        else:
            # Si la solicitud no fue exitosa, maneja el error según tu necesidad
            return {"error": "La solicitud a la API falló"}

    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        # Maneja excepciones de solicitudes HTTP (por ejemplo, problemas de red)
        return {"error": f"Error de solicitud: {e}"}
```

I need to know how to connect so I can see things in my mayan in my Django GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what a "mayan" is, but on what you're returning here ...

This:

```
return {"error": f"Error de solicitud: {e}"}
```

Is returning a Python dict object. That's not the same as a Json response, even if it might look like it.

Django has a `JsonResponse` class just for this purpose, you should use that.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects

Answer (score 1):

As of now you are not using django template to render your data, this is the reason you are not able to connect data in django Gui, you need to use django render function and template to display api response data in Gui/Template

*This code can help you:*

```
import requests
from django.shortcuts import render

@login_required
def f_facturaspendientes(request):
    url = 'http://localhost/api/v4/documents/'
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
        if response.status_code == 200:

            data = response.json()
            return render(request, 'your_template.html', {'data': data})
        else:
            return render(request, 'error_template.html', {'error_message': 'API request failed'})
    except Exception as e:
        return render(request, 'error_template.html', {'error_message': f"HTTP request error: {e}"})
```

Comment: OP specifically says it's an API, so no templates.